# Python convert gibbrish to hebrew

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, hebrew

here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-
array=["à","á","â","ã","ä","å","æ","ç","è","é","ê","ë","ì","í","î","ï","ð","ñ","ó","ô","õ","ö","ø","ù","ú","û","ü","ý","þ","ÿ"]
array1=["א","ב","ג","ד","ה","ו","ז","ח","ט","י","ך","כ","ל","ם","מ","ן","נ","ס","ע","ף","פ","ץ","צ","ק","ר","ש","ת"]
str="áï éäåãä"
message=""
for i in range(0,len(str)):
   s=str[i]
   index=-1
   for j in range(0,len(array)):
       if(array[j]==s):
           index=j
           break
   if(index!=-1):
   message+=array1[index]
   print array1[index]
print message
```

the error is:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

in line 2

I have a text file in hebrew, but it always displays in gibbrish, no matter what the encoding is. this is a python program to convert it to hebrew. original file is in IS0-8859-1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a single typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Martijn suggests, decoding your original file correctly would be a better solution.  If your file is Hebrew but displays `array` characters, it is probably being displayed as `latin1` or `cp1252` encoding.  `cp1255` looks like a close match.  Perhaps your `array1` isn't quite right.  Also note strings are iterable so you can simplify your arrays:

```
# coding: utf8
array  = u'àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñóôõöøùúûüýþÿ'
array1 = u'אבגדהוזחטיךכלםמןנסעףפץצקרשת'
print(array)
print(array1)
print(array.encode('cp1252').decode('cp1255',errors='replace'))
```

The last line above reverses the "incorrect" encoding and decodes it with `cp1255` (a Hebrew encoding) instead.  Output:

```
àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñóôõöøùúûüýþÿ
אבגדהוזחטיךכלםמןנסעףפץצקרשת
אבגדהוזחטיךכלםמןנסףפץצרשת��‎‏�
```

It's not a perfect match, but close enough that I think your original file was encoded with `cp1255`.

Comment: http://s16.postimg.org/a1b560dat/error.jpg
here is the result
@Mark Tolonen

Comment: I don't think your editor is configured properly.  It can't even `print(array)` and thinks the output encoding is `ascii`.  I use PythonWin, which comes with the [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) extensions.  Its output window is configured for UTF-8.

Comment: i use SPE Python(python 2.7) on ubuntu 12.04. but then why would this http://pastebin.com/1Ym2wgyz work? thanks @Mark Tolonen

Comment: You're sending raw per-encoded UTF-8 bytes to the terminal.  So you have a UTF-8 terminal but the environment isn't configured correctly.  If it was, the above `print(array)` would work.  Check the LANG environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

You used a `'` where you should have used a `"`:

```
'ÿ"
```

for the last entry in:

```
array=["à","á","â","ã","ä","å","æ","ç","è","é","ê","ë","ì","í","î","ï","ð","ñ","ó","ô","õ","ö","ø","ù","ú","û","ü","ý","þ",'ÿ"]
```

Make that single quote a double.

As for your translation program; it sounds as if your file encoding is incorrect, or is decoded incorrectly. Perhaps you should figure out the correct encoding instead, and not blindly replace Latin-1 bytes with UTF-8 sequences for Hebrew codepoints?

If you were to use the `codec` module to open the file with the correct codec and decode to Unicode, you most probably will find the data is correctly encoded anyway.

I **strongly** urge you to study up on Unicode, codecs and Python before you continue:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Comment: update:the file I want to translate is in 8859-1 western charset. I tries changing it to different hebrew charsets and its still doesn't work. when i paste it into [link] (http://gibberish.co.il/gibberish.html ) it works. however, i need it to work for large files as well. @Martijn Pieters

Comment: I have **no** idea what that link does; sorry, I cannot read Hebrew. If you do *have* to translate your text, use `unicode.translate()` with a table (a dictionary mapping ordinals (integers) to other codepoints).

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=bgtn9u&s=5 but forget about that website. you did not get the problem-it saved it in the wrong encoding, and now what you have to do is to write a script to fix it. i wrote a python one that did it now http://pastebin.com/1Ym2wgyz and it works. sorry i didn't made it clear it's impossible to change the file encoding so that it would be ok @Martijn Pieters